# Rydberg Blockade's experimental mechanism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, experimental-physics, quantum-computer

This idea for an experiment is for a high school competition (bl4s).

Utilizing a positron beam,can we knock out gas which has been energized to its Rydberg state.I plan to do this to verify when the blockade breakdown occurs by knocking out the atoms placed in a magnetic field as the atoms get ionized by positrons.

I doubt this as Mikhail Lukin stated in his lectures(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MXIVZLaCII) how lasers are used to produce these exited states and hold the atoms in place.

Does the system allow insertion of particle beams without disturbing the array.

Comment: In a gas beams will not interact much, but why positrons which by annihilation will be generating radiation?

Comment: The experiment is to be carried out at DESY,so if a high enough density of positron is generated one could ionize the gas and measure incoming atoms with a sensor placed along magnetic field or by accelerating them with an electric field.

Comment: Imo positrons with their high probability of annilation are unnecessary, an electron beam would only ionize and one would not have to think of gamma radiation hazards.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron

Comment: I was doubtful whether electron addition will be possible as the electrons in a rydberg atom are already in a highly exited state.As you point out electron addition,is it possible to launch particles into the array,for prof. Lukin stated the atoms are held in position with lasers,can one manage to create rydberg state gas independent of lasers?

Comment: I mean an electron beam that will kick out an electron from the last position getting the atom ionized.

Comment: So it is possible to do the experiment I stated above?Thanks for the help.